# StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack-overflow

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**

In page_load event i am calling

```
       if (mySession.Current._isCustomer)
       {

            Response.Redirect("Products.aspx");
       }
```

mySession class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ShoppingCartWebApp
{
    public class mySession
    {
            // private constructor
    private mySession() {}

// Gets the current session.
public static mySession Current
{
  get
  {
    mySession session =
      (mySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];
    if (session == null)
    {
      session = new mySession();
      HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
    }
    return session;
  }
}

// **** add your session properties here, e.g like this:
public string _Property1 { get; set; }
public DateTime _date { get; set; }
public String _loginId { get; set; }

public string _firstName { get; set; }
public string _userName { get; set; }
public string _role { get; set; }
public Boolean _isCustomer = false;
public Boolean _isAuth = false;
public Boolean _isGuest = true;
public ShoppingCart _cart = new ShoppingCart();

public ShoppingCart instance
{
    get
    {

        return _cart;
    }

    set
    {
        _cart = value;
    }
}



public void abandonSession()
{
   // _date = 
        _loginId = null;
        _firstName = null;
        _cart = null;
        _userName = null;
        _role = null;
        _isCustomer = false;
        _isAuth = false;
    }
    }
}
```

it gives a stackoverflow exception. why?

ShoppingCart Class:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    #region ListCart

    public List<CartItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr.connString);
    #endregion

    #region CartSession

    public ShoppingCart cart;

    public ShoppingCart() 
    {

        if (mySession.Current._cart == null)
        {
            cart = new ShoppingCart();
            cart.Items = new List<CartItem>();

            if (mySession.Current._isCustomer)
                cart.Items = ShoppingCart.loadCart(mySession.Current._loginId);

            mySession.Current._cart = cart;
        }
        else
        {
            cart = mySession.Current._cart;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: how do you use this singleton class? as i see, there is no problem

Comment: edited forgot to include

Comment: What line is th exception occuring on?  What's the calling code look like?  Also, I strongly suggest you follow normal .Net conventions; no public fields, capitalize class, property and method names, don't use names starting with underscores for public / protected members (AbandonSession, FirstName, etc).  This will make it easier for the C# people here to read your code.

Comment: Can we see the code for the `ShoppingCart` class? If it is calling into `mySession`, that could be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line of code causes infinite loop and stack overflow :

```
if (mySession.Current._isCustomer)
                cart.Items = ShoppingCart.loadCart(mySession.Current._loginId);
```

it is initialized by each instance of mysession class. and its using its parent class.

even using singleton mySession can not solve the problem.

when this code is executing :

```
session = new mySession();
```

it tries to initialize new **ShoppingCard**. shopping card asks for singleton instance of mysession. this line of code is not executed yet :

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
```

so goes to create a new instance of my session and ...

this means stack overflow !

you can correct it like this :

```
public static mySession Current
{
  get
  {
    mySession session =
      (mySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];
    if (session == null)
    {
      session = new mySession();
      HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
      session._cart = new ShoppingCart(); //initialize your shoppoing car after adding variable to session !
    }
    return session;
  }
}

public ShoppingCart _cart;// = new ShoppingCart(); remove initialization
```

look at my comments in code.

Comment: i have provided code in edited question....
if i comment that if statement ...everything works

the current page is Login.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes because of the relationship between `mySession` and `ShoppingCart`.

`mySession` has a member variable defined like so:

```
public ShoppingCart _cart = new ShoppingCart();
```

When the constructor of `mySession` is called, an instance of `ShoppingCart` is instantiated. When the constructor of `ShoppingCart` executes, it calls the `mySession.Current` static property. Because the constructor of `ShoppingCart` was called from within this same property (remember, we are still creating an instance of `mySession` in the original static call), it continues to recurse in this way until a `StackOverflowException` is raised.

To fix this, I suggest you take a look at your `ShoppingCart` class. Firstly, why does it need an instance of itself as a member variable? Secondly, if `ShoppingCart` needs to know information about the contents of `mySession`, your encapsulation is not correct. I suggest you pass the information needed into the constructor of `ShoppingCart` to avoid making a call back to `mySession.Current`.

Answer (score 0):

Given your updated question, I think if you properly followed .Net naming guidelines (as outlined in my comment on your question), you should be able to easily figure out where the problem is.  I suspect your calling code is similar, and not following the guidelines is obscuring what is actually happening from what you think is happening.

As a first step I would recommend doing this cleanup; it will likely make it clear where you're causing the overflow.

Comment: Naming conventions can not raise stackoverflow exception !

Comment: No, but they can make it really hard to follow the code.  I'm suggesting he follow the conventions to help figure out where the error is occuring.  I'd bet he's using a property when he's intending to access a field.